# How to post a complex model to action?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My model defined:

```
public class RulePageViewModel
{
    public List<RuleItem> RuleItemList { get; set; }

    public RuleViewModel RuleViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

My action defined:

```
public JsonResult Save(RulePageViewModel viewmodel)
```

I try to post json, viewmodel.RuleItemList.Count > 0, but instance in viewmodel.RuleItemList is null.
If use model bind,how to bind a list in view?

I haven't try to bind model, just use ajax to post json to action. I think it will work, but failed Code:

```
var s = { "RuleItemList": [{ "RuleGroupId": 1, "RuleGroupName": "", "Keywords": "ajax", "ResponseDescribe": "dadhsa" }], "RuleViewModel": { "RuleGroupId": 14, "RuleList": [{ "RuleId": 567, "SourceId": 125, "KeyValue": "callback", "SourceType": 0 }], "SourceList": [] } };
var ss = JSON.stringify(s);
var json = JSON.parse(ss);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

---

OK, I solved it:

```
var json = { "RuleItemList": [{ "RuleGroupId": 1, "RuleGroupName": "", "Keywords": "ajax", "ResponseDescribe": "dadhsa" }], "RuleViewModel": { "RuleGroupId": 14, "RuleList": [{ "RuleId": 567, "SourceId": 125, "KeyValue": "callback", "SourceType": 0 }], "SourceList": [] } };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Add your view code...

Comment: Yes, add your view code. This is possible, but the model binder must be able to rebuild the model from the request.

Comment: There is a very good post on [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should do something like that:

```
    @for(var i = 0;i<Model.RuleItemList.Count;++i)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RuleItemList[i].Name);
    }

    @Html.EditorFor(m = > m.RuleViewModel.PropertyOne);
    @Html.EditorFor(m = > m.RuleViewModel.PropertyTow);
    @Html.EditorFor(m = > m.RuleViewModel.PropertyThree);
```

Which will eventually generate something like that to the html:

```
<input type="text" name="RuleViewModel.PropertyOne" value="" />
<input type="text" name="RuleViewModel.PropertyTow" value="" />
<input type="text" name="RuleViewModel.PropertyThree" value="" />
```

Now because you did not place any view code or any code from your `RuleItem` an `RuleViewModel`  classes that is going to be some problem to specifically answer your question so please post more info but in general you should understand from what i wrote here how to implement such a from that will post the data to your controller action so that the `Model Binder` will know which properties to bind..

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx